# Use typings for a CDN

Tags: typescript, cdn, typescript-typings

I want to use a CDN for accessing a JSON validation library, for it is supposed to be a little bit faster (it gets the file from the closest available server in the CDN).

This is the JSON validation library:
https://github.com/epoberezkin/ajv#using-in-browser

It directs me to this CDN:
https://cdnjs.com/libraries/ajv

So I include that in my HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ajv/4.10.4/ajv.min.js" integrity="sha256-LtA3VfycAam30/5e2Fq1f2tg8eIiFMOVWp1NDd6jmUU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
```

Now the typings... I ran `npm install --save-dev @types/ajv` and it installed.

node_modules/@types/ajv/package.json:

```
{
  "_args": [
    [
      {
        "raw": "@types/ajv",
        "scope": "@types",
        "escapedName": "@types%2fajv",
        "name": "@types/ajv",
        "rawSpec": "",
        "spec": "latest",
        "type": "tag"
      },
      "C:\\Users\\si556577\\Documents\\SSWebApp\\app\\Iag.DI.Web.SupplierApp"
    ]
  ],
  "_from": "@types/ajv@latest",
  "_id": "@types/ajv@1.0.0",
  "_inCache": true,
  "_installable": true,
  "_location": "/@types/ajv",
  "_npmOperationalInternal": {
    "host": "packages-12-west.internal.npmjs.com",
    "tmp": "tmp/ajv-1.0.0.tgz_1482502603556_0.6872997884638608"
  },
  "_npmUser": {
    "name": "types",
    "email": "ts-npm-types@microsoft.com"
  },
  "_phantomChildren": {},
  "_requested": {
    "raw": "@types/ajv",
    "scope": "@types",
    "escapedName": "@types%2fajv",
    "name": "@types/ajv",
    "rawSpec": "",
    "spec": "latest",
    "type": "tag"
  },
  "_requiredBy": [
    "#DEV:/",
    "#USER"
  ],
  "_resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@types/ajv/-/ajv-1.0.0.tgz",
  "_shasum": "4fb2440742f2f6c30e7fb0797b839fc6f696682a",
  "_shrinkwrap": null,
  "_spec": "@types/ajv",
  "_where": "C:\\Users\\si556577\\Documents\\SSWebApp\\app\\Iag.DI.Web.SupplierApp",
  "author": "",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/epoberezkin/ajv/issues"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "ajv": "*"
  },
  "deprecated": "This is a stub types definition for ajv (https://github.com/epoberezkin/ajv). ajv provides its own type definitions, so you don't need @types/ajv installed!",
  "description": "Stub TypeScript definitions entry for ajv, which provides its own types definitions",
  "devDependencies": {},
  "directories": {},
  "dist": {
    "shasum": "4fb2440742f2f6c30e7fb0797b839fc6f696682a",
    "tarball": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@types/ajv/-/ajv-1.0.0.tgz"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/epoberezkin/ajv#readme",
  "license": "MIT",
  "main": "",
  "maintainers": [
    {
      "name": "types",
      "email": "ts-npm-types@microsoft.com"
    }
  ],
  "name": "@types/ajv",
  "optionalDependencies": {},
  "readme": "ERROR: No README data found!",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/epoberezkin/ajv.git"
  },
  "scripts": {},
  "typings": null,
  "version": "1.0.0"
}
```

and it also added this to package.json:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@types/ajv": "^1.0.0",
```

In code I use it like this:

```
validateJSONSchema(json) {
    var ajv = new Ajv();
    var valid = ajv.validate(this.schema, json);
    if (!valid) {
        console.log(ajv.errors);
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

The code works, however in the vs code I'm getting the compile time error: `Cannot find name "Ajv"`

How do I make my typings work? I have only ever used typings when I install the package locally rather than use a CDN. Can typings even work when using a CDN?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's noted in `ajv`'s `package.json` file that `@types/ajv` is now deprecated and the typings are included with the package iteself:

> This is a stub types definition for ajv (https://github.com/epoberezkin/ajv). ajv provides its own type definitions, so you don't need @types/ajv installed!

However, the typings included with the package itself are intended to be used like this:

```ts
import * as Ajv from "ajv";
let ajv = new Ajv(...);
```

So TypeScript is not going to be happy with the typings unless `import` statements are used.

This means that if you want to use the CDN, you will have to configure your module bundler to do so. It's not going to be enough to include the CDN `<script>` and have `Ajv` available as a global.

How you do that depends upon the bundler you are using.

Comment: And if you're using no bundlers... Oh well, sucks to be (you/me/everyone...). I've been searching for this for entirely too long. All I want is typings for Vue (installed via npm) with the script loaded from CDN. It's ridiculous. :(